# Calculating minimum sample size for non-Gaussian distribution

Tags: nonparametric, sample-size

I have a population (n=36931) that follows non-Gaussian distribution with the following attributes of one discrete variable, x:

Min: 0
Mean x = 9666
SD x = 66754

I want to compare means of x for different samples drawn from the population against the population mean of x.

The data are counts and there are many 0 values.

What method should I use to determine the minimum sample size?

Comment: If there are a lot of exact zeros that's very important information. Please add it to your question. Is the variable otherwise (at least notionally) continuous, or is it discrete?

Comment: Any thoughts yet?